# How to make transactions based on the frequency of transaction in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django, but I'm working on a project that allows users to create transactions. I would like to be able to create transactions that are recurring, based on a frequency. For example, a user could create a recurring transaction that is paid out every month.

I'm not sure how to best implement this functionality. I've been looking at the django-scheduler library, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to go.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to implement this functionality?

Here is the transaction model that I'm using:

```
class Type(models.TextChoices):
        """Class for transaction types."""
        DEPOSIT =  'Deposit'
        PAYMENT =  'Payment'

class Frequency(models.TextChoices):
        """Class for tansactin frequency"""
        ONETIME = 'One-time'
        DAILY = 'Daily'
        EVERY_WEEK = 'Every week'
        EVERY_TWO_WEEKS = 'Every two weeks'
        EVERY_THREE_WEEKS = 'Every three weeks'
        EVERY_MONTH = 'Every month'
        EVERY_TWO_MONTHS = 'Every two months'
        EVERY_QUARTER = 'Every quarter'
        EVERY_SIX_MONTHS = 'Every six months'
        EVERY_YEAR = 'Every year'
        EVERY_TWO_YEARS = 'Every two years'

class Transaction(models.Model):
    """Transaction model."""

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    transaction_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        choices=Type.choices,
        default=Type.PAYMENT,
    )
    transaction_date = models.DateField()
    frequency = models.CharField(
        max_length=30,
        choices=Frequency.choices,
        default=Frequency.ONETIME,
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='transactions',
    )
    subcategory = models.ForeignKey(
        SubCategory,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='transactions',
    )
    payee = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Transaction'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Transactions'
        ordering = ['-transaction_date', 'payee','category']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.transaction_type}: {self.amount} to {self.payee}'
```